# Ionic - Angular build error - Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular, ionic5, angular-builder

I am building an Ionic-Angular app. The app runs well on browser (with ionic serve), but it fails when I try to build it.. I am getting a reference error. How can I find out where is the error exactly?

[image]

Comment: Run it with --verbose and add the output in you question.

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, its sorted out.. --verbose neither gave me any clue.. I needed more information. So I had to modify the angular compiler js and add some console logging there to understand that error and then I fixed it. But I still have question regarding the error. I'll put another question with my confusion shortly. In short, I declared a variable in template *ngFor="object of objectArray; let z = false", and then was using this z inside the inner dom elements and that caused me the error. Temporarily I moved that z property within the object.

Comment: Ok no problem .